# Speech Recognition with Buildozer

Tags: python, speech-recognition, buildozer

I am writing an application for android, where i am using SpeachRecognition library to translate speech into text using Google API.
My program works fine with a kivy GUI on ubuntu 16.04 python 3.5, so how can i build this app using buildozer ? what should the requirements be ?
I have modified the requirements in buildozer.spec to become : **" requirements = kivy , hostpython2 , SpeechRecognition , pyaudio "** , but this raise the following error : **" Failed building wheel for pyaudio "**.

**Edit : ( part of the output of command "Buildozer android debug")**

[INFO]:    # Installing pure Python modules

> [INFO]:    The requirements (SpeechRecognition, pyaudio) don't have recipes, attempting to install them with pip
>
> [INFO]:    If this fails, it may mean that the module has compiled components and needs a recipe.
>
> [INFO]:    -> directory context /home/proctronics/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build
>
> [INFO]:    -> running virtualenv --python=python2.7 venv
>
> objs_paths are ['/home/proctronics/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python2/collated_objects']
>
> Copying libraries
>
> [INFO]:    Creating a requirements.txt file for the Python modules
>
> [INFO]:    Installing Python modules with pip
>
> [INFO]:    If this fails with a message about /bin/false, this probably means the package cannot be installed with pip as it needs a compilation recipe.
>
> [INFO]:    -> running bash -c source venv/bin/activate && env CC=/bin/false CXX=/bin/false PYTHONPATH=/home/proctronics/Desktop/test/.b...(and 259 more)
>
> working:                                     Exception in thread background thread for pid 3095:n/python2.7 -u -c "import setupt...(and 509 more)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
>
> self.run()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
>
> self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
>
> File "/home/proctronics/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 1540, in wrap
>
> fn(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/home/proctronics/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 2459, in background_thread
>
> handle_exit_code(exit_code)
>
> File "/home/proctronics/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 2157, in fn
>
> return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
>
> File "/home/proctronics/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
>
> raise exc
>
> ErrorReturnCode_1:
>
> RAN: /bin/bash -c source venv/bin/activate && env CC=/bin/false CXX=/bin/false PYTHONPATH=/home/proctronics/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/blue/lib/python2.7/site-packages pip install --target '/home/proctronics/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/blue/lib/python2.7/site-packages' --no-deps -r requirements.txt
>
> STDOUT:
>
> Collecting SpeechRecognition (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
>
> Using cached SpeechRecognition-3.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>
> Collecting pyaudio (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
>
> Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
>
> Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
>
> Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyaudio ... error
>
> Complete output from command /home/proctronics/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/venv/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-QShDtG/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('
>
> ', '
>
> ');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmp9IBfgPpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
>
> running bdist_wheel
>
> running build
>
> running build_py
>
> creating build
>
> creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
>
> copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
>
> running build_ext
>
> building '_portaudio' extension
>
> creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
>
> creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
>
> /bin/false -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/_portaudiomodule.o
>
> error: command '/bin/false' failed with exit status 1
>
> ---
>
> Failed building wheel for pyaudio
>
> Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
>
> Failed to build pyaudio
>
> Installing collected packages: SpeechRecognition, pyaudio
>
> Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
>
> Complete output from command /home/proctronics/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/venv/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-QShDtG/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('
>
> ', '
>
> ');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ObcFB4-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/proctronics/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/venv/include/site/python2.7/pyaudio --home=/tmp/tmp93Wh_5:
>
> running install
>
> running build
>
> running build_py
>
> creating build
>
> creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
>
> copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
>
> running build_ext
>
> building '_portaudio' extension
>
> creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
>
> creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
>
> /bin/false -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/_portaudiomodule.o
>
> error: command '/bin/false' failed with exit status 1
>
> ---
>
> Command "/home/proctronics/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/venv/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-QShDtG/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('
>
> ', '
>
> ');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ObcFB4-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/proctronics/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/venv/include/site/python2.7/pyaudio --home=/tmp/tmp93Wh_5" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-QShDtG/pyaudio/
>
> STDERR:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
>
> "**main**", fname, loader, pkg_name)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
>
> exec code in run_globals
>
> File "/home/proctronics/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 905, in
>
> main()
>
> File "/home/proctronics/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 902, in main
>
> ToolchainCL()
>
> File "/home/proctronics/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 508, in **init**
>
> getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
>
> File "/home/proctronics/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 147, in wrapper_func
>
> build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
>
> File "/home/proctronics/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 190, in build_dist_from_args
>
> build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx)
>
> File "pythonforandroid/build.py", line 585, in build_recipes
>
> File "pythonforandroid/build.py", line 626, in run_pymodules_install
>
> File "pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 175, in shprint
>
> File "/home/proctronics/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 863, in next
>
> self.wait()
>
> File "/home/proctronics/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 792, in wait
>
> self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
>
> File "/home/proctronics/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
>
> raise exc
>
> sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:
>
> RAN: /bin/bash -c source venv/bin/activate && env CC=/bin/false CXX=/bin/false PYTHONPATH=/home/proctronics/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/blue/lib/python2.7/site-packages pip install --target '/home/proctronics/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/blue/lib/python2.7/site-packages' --no-deps -r requirements.txt
>
> STDOUT:
>
> Collecting SpeechRecognition (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
>
> Using cached SpeechRecognition-3.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>
> Collecting pyaudio (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
>
> Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
>
> Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
>
> Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyaudio ... error
>
> Complete output from command /home/proctronics/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/venv/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-QShDtG/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('
>
> ', '
>
> ');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmp9IBfgPpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
>
> running bdist_wheel
>
> running build
>
> running build_py
>
> creating build
>
> creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
>
> copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
>
> running build_ext
>
> building '_portaudio' extension
>
> creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
>
> creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
>
> /bin/false -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/_portaudiomodule.o
>
> error: command '/bin/false' failed with exit status 1
>
> ---
>
> Failed building wheel for pyaudio
>
> Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
>
> Failed to build pyaudio
>
> Installing collected packages: SpeechRecognition, pyaudio
>
> Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
>
> Complete output from command /home/proctronics/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/venv/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-QShDtG/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('
>
> ', '
>
> ');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ObcFB4-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/proctronics/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/venv/include/site/python2.7/pyaudio --home=/tmp/tmp93Wh_5:
>
> running install
>
> running build
>
> running build_py
>
> creating build
>
> creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
>
> copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
>
> running build_ext
>
> building '_portaudio' extension
>
> creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
>
> creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
>
> /bin/false -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/_portaudiomodule.o
>
> error: command '/bin/false' failed with exit status 1
>
> ---
>
> Command "/home/proctronics/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/venv/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-QShDtG/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('
>
> ', '
>
> ');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ObcFB4-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/proctronics/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/venv/include/site/python2.7/pyaudio --home=/tmp/tmp93Wh_5" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-QShDtG/pyaudio/
>
> STDERR:
>
> ## Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=blue --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy,hostpython2,SpeechRecognition,pyaudio --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/home/proctronics/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build
>
> ## Buildozer failed to execute the last command
>
> ## The error might be hidden in the log above this error
>
> ## Please read the full log, and search for it before
>
> ## raising an issue with buildozer itself.
>
> ## In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please be more verbose? Consider editing the question and adding the full error log

Comment: @Juggernaut that is the full output after trying to install the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [link](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/195), only pure python package can be installed automatically, all the packages that depends of binary compilation must have a recipe written.

A recipe is a script that contain the “definition” of a module to compile. The directory layout of a recipe for a is something like:

> python-for-android/recipes//recipe.sh
>
> python-for-android/recipes//patches/
>
> python-for-android/recipes//patches/fix-path.patch When
> building, all the recipe build must go to:
>
> python-for-android/build// For example, if
> you want to create a recipe for sdl, do:
>
> cd python-for-android/recipes mkdir sdl cp recipe.sh.tmpl
>
> sdl/recipe.sh sed -i 's#XXX#sdl#' sdl/recipe.sh Then, edit the
>
> sdl/recipe.sh to adjust other information (version, url) and complete
> build function.